# Nested flexboxes (in both dimensions)

Tags: css, flexbox

I am trying to understand the use of nested flexboxes. There is nice article about flexboxes https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/. It divides the attributes of flexboxes into parent and item groups. Am I understanding correctly: if I have 3 nested flexboxes then the middle flexbox acts both in role of the item and in role of the parent and therefore its CSS attributes should include both parent and item attributes for flexboxes?

I have code https://jsfiddle.net/tomrhodes/szmt7pL8/ in which I am trying to apply the theory in practice:

```
<div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row2">HEADER</div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row2">header</div>
      <div class="container">content</div>
      <div class="row2">footer</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row2">FOOTER</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  border: solid magenta;
}

.row2 {
  background: #f8f9fa;
  margin-top: 20px;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  -webkit-flex: 0 1 auto;
}

.container {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  -webkit-flex-flow: column;
  height: auto;
  border: solid blue;
}
```

I would like to arrive the the solution with 2 features:

- Outer flexbox (container) should fill the entire space of the available screen. At present it is somehow bounded;
- The most inner flexbox (with *content* text) should be the flexible area of the screen in both dimensions - if screen is made wider or longer, then this content are should expand and it should shrink in the opposite case. It should be the only flexible are of the present screen.

What is wrong with my nesting?

Comment: One thing to watch out for when nesting flexboxes - safari and some versions of ie really don't like it and you get some weird results.  Looking at your code - your outer container is "bound" because it's parent has no height or styles set

Comment: I am making B2B application and we have decided not support Safari, we will require to use Chrome or Firefox, it is fine with B2B applications.

Comment: Doesn't look like theres a problem if you check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/986unvmt/

Comment: wrapper class name is the only difference, I don't understand why those fiddles behave differently. I986unvmt is better, but it is not complete solution - content part should be flexible in the vertical direction as well.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that it is not possible to use one div as nested flexbox in box roles - as item for outer flexbox and as parent for inside content. Another div should be introduced. The solution is here: https://jsfiddle.net/tomrhodes/8pf1q706/

```
<div class="outsidebox">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="headerstyle">header</div>
    <div class="contentstyle">
      <div class="outsidebox">
        <div class="headerstyle">header 2</div>
        <div class="contentstyle">content 2</div>
        <div class="footerstyle">footer 2</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footerstyle">footer</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And CSS is:

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  border: solid magenta;
}

.row2 {
  background: #f8f9fa;
  margin-top: 20px;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  -webkit-flex: 0 1 auto;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  -webkit-flex-flow: column;
  height: 100%;
  border: solid blue;
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  height: 100%;
  border: solid blue;
}

.outsidebox {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  height: 100%;
  border: solid purple;
}

.headerstyle {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  border: solid green;
}

.contentstyle {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  border: solid green;
}

.footerstyle {
  flex: 0 1 40px;
  border: solid green;
}
```